# Which of the following conditions are necessary for the positive integer $n$ to be divisible by 6? Which of them are sufficient?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

**Question:**
Are my answers correct? I am particularly concerned with (ii) and (vii).

> **Which of the following conditions are necessary for the positive integer $n$ to be divisible by 6? Which of them are sufficient?**
>
> (i) 3 divides $n$.
>
> (ii) 9 divides $n$.
>
> (iii) 12 divides $n$.
>
> (iv) $n =$ 12.
>
> (v) 6 divides $n^2$.
>
> (vi) 2 divides $n$ and 3 divides $n$.
>
> (vii) 2 divides $n$ or 3 divides $n$.

**Answers:**

(i) necessary,

(ii) none,

(iii) sufficient,

(iv) sufficient,

(v) sufficient and necessary,

(vi) sufficient and necessary,

(vii) necessary.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score -1):

I think that your answer to numbers II and VII are correct.

$9$ is not a factor of $6$ so is not necessary.

Since $n$ might be divisible by $2$ but may not be divisible by $3$ (e.g. $4$) and since $n$ might be divisible by $3$ but may not be divisible by $2$ (e.g. $9$) VII is insufficient but must be necessary.

Comment: So you are saying (vii) is neither sufficient, nor necessary?

Comment: iit may be necessary

Comment: "$6$ divides $n$" $\implies$ "$2$ divides $n$ *or* $3$ divides $n$" - therefore, condition (vii) is necessary. However, using an exclusive-or would make (vii) into a sufficient condition for the opposite statement, "$6$ does not divide $n$"

Comment: TRUE on ur part